# Exporting in Premiere from mpg 720 to h.264 1920

Tags: premiere

What do i gain / does it make sense to export video that is originally loaded in Premiere as:

mpg 720x576 /25fps / 7000kbps

to

h.264 1920x1080 / 25fps / 12000kbs target (15000 max) ?

I am just adding lower third for few sec, no other modifications of the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** I assume your 720x576 video uses anamorphic pixels, making for a 16:9 resolution. Still, there is no added benefit to the higher resolution, as it won't increase the quality of your video. On the other hand, your video file will be much larger. Export in your original resolution with a high bitrate instead (not higher than your source material though). If you need to export an uncompressed copy, use a visually lossless codec such as DNxHD or Apple ProRes.

That is, assuming by 'loaded into Premiere' you mean this is the resolution of your source material. If you are referring to your sequence and your source material actually has a higher resolution, create a new sequence with the respective settings, copy everything from your current sequence to the new one and export that using the same resolution as your source video.

Comment: Ok. I have data rate of 12000kbps, and total bitrate of 12384kbs. Which one should i aim ?

Comment: @BigBrother2010  The total bit rate includes all streams -- like audio. The video data rate is 12000kbps, that's what you aim to reduce, although you should apply the same logic to any audio streams: don't bother exceeding the original specs. Plus, a given bit rate at .h264 can outperform that same rate in mpeg2, so odds are 7Mbps is more than sufficient.